# Can I use TRIM and TRUNC function in oracle?

Tags: oracle, function, trim

using trunc function I am getting below o/p
Output :01-APR-2017

I want only APR and remove rest part 
Can I use trim or sub-string in my query?

NOTE:- I want value in DATE format  not in character format .

Comment: If you want only APR that’s not anything that can be in a date format. What exactly do you want?

Comment: It would perhaps help to have an example of your code and how it will appear in the end result.

Comment: `'APR'` is a string; `01-APR-2017` is a date. If you explain how you want to use the outcome we can tell you to write the code.

Comment: I recommend you to to read a bit about how `date` datatype works in Oracle or in any programming language in general, before posting such riddles such as "I want value in DATE format" .

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear. To truncate a date to month:

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'MM') from dual;
```

To get only the month (as a string, a date always includes year and day):

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 'MON') from dual;
```

If your goal is to work with date columns and compare them perhaps this will help? If not please be more explicit about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response ,

select to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 'MON') from dual;
this will CONVERT my date in CHARACTER format I want in DATE format.To achieve my goal of  getting MONTHS as per Calender wise..not by Alphabetical wise

Comment: You can't get a month in DATE format because a DATE by definition also contains year and day (and time). To get a date with only the month part (day becomes 1) use TRUNC(d, 'MM'). Then you have the month in date format. If on the other hand you want to extract the month from a date and keep only the month part you can get it as a string or a number. String see above, number try to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'MM')) which will be a number between 1 and 12.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only month use extract function select extract(month from to_date('01-APR-2017','dd-mon-yyyy')) from dual, this will return month as 4 not APR